# Unable to add more logic bricks

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I recently began experimenting with BGE (Blender Game Engine).

I’ve got a basic character, with a child containing the actual model (the top level character is simply a hidden physics body shape).

The top level character contains all my sensors, controllers and actuators for movement, looking around, etc.

I reopened blender this morning and found that I can no longer add logic bricks to my top level character.

On the “add” menu, every item from each of the options (sensor etc) is greyed out, so does nothing when clicked. I can delete existing bricks, I can disconnect and reconnect things, and the bricks themselves still work, but I cannot add any new bricks.

This is specific to this node, I can add scripts on other nodes,  but not the top level character, or sub nodes of the top level character.

Is this something I’ve managed to change when editing? Or is this some build in limit? [image: Bricks] [image: Problem] [image: Hierarchy]

Comment: http://take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: Yeah sorry, didn’t have time

Comment: But wouldn't it take *longer* to physically take pictures of your monitor, load them onto your computer, crop them, then upload them? Taking a screenshot takes very little time at all.

Comment: I wrote this on my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I never had that and I can't imagine what the cause of it could be.

As a workaround I suggest to replace the object, with another one. You can copy the logic via <kbd>space</kbd> copy logic bricks to selected (in a similar way you can "copy game properties").

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally get greyed-out, add logic-brick UI panels when I've imported new objects and the cursor selection is automatically set to none because Blender is confused.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, turns out the Meshes I wanted to add more logic bricks were hidden in the 3d view port, which is why I wasn't able to add more logic bricks. Unhide your mesh within the 3d view-port, and you should be able to add more.